How to translate Workday SoapUI API calls into Postman and C# / .NET with same endpoint but different operation?
I am working on API project using Workday APIs. Based on the data given by Workday, I could test API calls from Soap UI and get responses back.
Here under this Workday Revenue Management Module, we have different operations like:
Get_Customers,
Get_Customer_Invoices,
Get_Customer_Invoice_Adjustments....etc

For all these operations, it is the same endpoint from SoapUI. We are specifying UserName, Password and WSS-Password type.
Now I am trying to move this to Postman using "Export Swagger/Open API Definition". It is throwing an error "Project is missing REST APIs".
Also I am trying to implement this in C# and on .NET.
Does anyone have any thoughts on this?
Appreciate your time.


Finally by adding the WSS-Password Type as the Security Section in the SoapHeader, Postman call worked.
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>

</soapenv:Header>
